# Set timestamp column in DB2 table using SSIS

Tags: ssis, timestamp, db2, sql-update, expression

I am trying to create an update command expression in expression builder to update the timestamp field.

```
@[User::FinalSQLPolicy] =  "UPDATE ZDBA.ACE_POLICY_XREF SET APX_ACE_POLICY_NBR= '"+ @[User::CNTRCTID] +"',APX_LAST_MAINT_TMSP=' GETDATE() '  where APX_PRS_POLICY_NBR='"+  @[User::APXPRSPOLICYNBR] +"'"
```

APX_LAST_MAINT_TMSP is the field i want to store the current timestamp.

I am getting error like below

Expression cannot be evaluated.

> Attempt to parse the expression "  "UPDATE ZDBA.ACE_POLICY_XREF SET
>   APX_ACE_POLICY_NBR= '"+ @[User::CNTRCTID] +"',APX_LAST_MAINT_TMSP='"
>   GETDATE()" '  where APX_PRS_POLICY_NBR='"+  @[User::APXPRSPOLICYNBR]
>   +"'"" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed,
>   or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

Can anyone help me to correct the above expression?

Comment: Is `GetDate()` a valid DB2 function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function, which is equivalent of the datetime date type of `GETDATE()`.  DB2 also has `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIME` functions, which return the current date (YYYYMMDD) and time (HHMMSS) respectively.  More details on these can be found in the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_specialregistersintro.html).